# In a Windows batch file, how can I cd to a single subdirectory with a variable name in a directory?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a folder with a constant name  and inside it is a single subfolder with a variable name.

How can I change directory with a cd command into the variable named subfolder in a Windows single batch file if the name is not constant but there is only a single subfolder?

EDIT:

Tried shelter's suggestion - didn't work - results as shown below, may because there are two other dirs present - . and ..[image]

EDIT 2:

Found it did work if I put a character in front of the star eg cd 15* if the ony subdir name starts with 15

Comment: Are there other files in the folder that contains the sub-folder? If no other files, only the variably named sub-folder, then try `cd c:\my\path\special\*` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to build a small batch file. Try this one:

```html
@echo OFF
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /D /B ') do set "MyDir=%%a"
cd %MyDir%
```

the /D focusses on directories only, while /B reduces the output.
Keep in mind that this will only work in your described environment. If you have more then one folder in the subfolder, it will not work.